# Annotator dependencies: UIMA Type Capabilities?

Tags: java, annotations, nlp, uima, dkpro-core

In my UIMA application, I have some annotators that must run after a certain annotator has run.

At first, I thought about aggregating these annotators together, but I have other annotators that are also dependent on this (and other) annotator, which makes aggregating hard and/or unpractical.

I read about Type Capabilities, which, if I understood correctly, tell UIMA that certain Types (Annotations) must be present, when used as `Input Type`. I was hoping that UIMA will give me something like a warning when running pipelines without Annotators that have some Output Types that are declared as Input Types of the used Annotator.
Instead, the annotators keep running/processing as usual.

Is there a way to achieve what I want, or is this just unnecessary?
I am currently using the SimplePipeline if that matters.

TL;DR: My goal is that Annotators refuse to run if there are certain other Annotators are missing in the Pipeline/scheduled after these Annotators

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UIMA the primary way in which one assures that the annotations you need are present for your annotator is to aggregate annotators together. So to answer your question, that is how you are going to achieve what you want because what you want to do (have UIMA figure our all your dependencies through Type Capabilities and provide warnings) is neither possible nor practical with a collection of stand alone annotators.

My question back to you is, why is it so hard to figure our dependencies by making aggregate annotators? Do you realize that you can aggregate aggregate pipelines? They should have all of their annotation dependencies intact if they are functioning correctly and provide a list of what they output so you can use them as input for the construction of your own pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where do you see the confusion with terminology? It is clear to me that a single annotator is no pipeline :-) Also, it isn't hard for me to aggregate annotators, I was just wondering if this is a preferred way for running dependent annotators because I would have to aggregate multiple annotators from which most annotators have no dependency to others. For examlple: Annotator B needs to run after A; C needs to run after A. So I aggregate it to A,B,C, although B and C have no dependency. I would prefer to aggregate to A,B and A;C, but A would then run twice.

Comment: A pipeline refers to a CollectionReader + some annotators (treating Consumers as annotator swhich they basically are under the hood). So when you wrote: **I was hoping that UIMA will give me something like a warning when running pipelines without Annotators** I just wanted to check to make sure we had the same definition since you were talking about pipelines with no annotators. To better answer your question about dependencies I would do A,B,C as one pipeline even if B and C have no dependency - it's normal to use only a subset of the annotations available in the CAS.

Comment: But the sentence did not end there: ".. without Annotators that have some Output Types that are declared as Input Types of the used Annotator.". The reason why I asked the question is because I find it kind of odd to aggregate Annotators that have nothing in common except a dependency. As a programmer, this is against my persuation of "packaging" things together :-)

Comment: I fixed my answer to remove the stuff about the pipeline misunderstanding. I wouldn't think of it as packaging stuff together, think of it more as just annotating a document and needing to be sure that the stuff any particular annotator needs to do its job has already been produced. In any case, it may be easier to just compose your aggregate pipelines with uimaFit as you need them.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Yes, I use uimaFit for aggregating the engines. Until I find another solution, I will aggregate them as suggested. One more thing: If the type capability does not enforce the order, what is it used for?

Comment: To tell the truth I never used the Type Capacities, I always assumed that they were as documentation to let people know what the annotator required and produced. They could be used to check that the order is reasonable though, but I don't think this has been implemented. A good idea though! Maybe file a JIRA ticket with the UIMA list. :)

Comment: There is a `CapabilityLanguageFlowController` in UIMA: From the JavaDoc: FlowController for the CapabilityLanguageFlow, which uses a linear flow but may skip some of the AEs in the flow if they do not handle the language of the current document or if their outputs have already been produced by a previous AE in the flow.

Answer (score 3):

UIMA is a very flexible framework. By default, capabilities are not used and if present are purely informational. However, check out e.g. the [CapabilityLanguageFlowController](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/uimaj/trunk/uimaj-core/src/main/java/org/apache/uima/flow/impl/CapabilityLanguageFlowController.java):

```
FlowController for the CapabilityLanguageFlow, which uses a linear flow 
but may skip some of the AEs in the flow if they do not handle the language
of the current document or if their outputs have already been produced by
a previous AE in the flow.
```

You could configure your aggregate to use such a flow controller and then you can benefit from capabilities.

*Disclosure: I am working on the Apache UIMA project (but I didn't use the CapabilityLanguageFlowController so far)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already had a look at the flow controllers.  I might be able to use them to enforce the presence of my annotators, but so far this seems to be a bit overkill for my app :-)

Answer (score 1):

UIMA does not enforce that certain Types (Annotations) must be present. This is a feature that allows flexibility.

You can however document your UIMAfit annotator with @TypeCapability annotation. A typical use of this annotation might look something like:

```
@TypeCapability(
  inputs="org.apache.uima.fit.type.Token", 
  outputs="org.apache.uima.fit.type.Token:pos")
```

Still, this does not enforce type dependencies. What I did on [one project](https://github.com/BlueBrain/bluima) was to implement [my own checking system](https://github.com/BlueBrain/bluima/blob/fa96a72640c567a69b5f970ad1fd4f983680261e/modules/bluima_scripting/src/main/java/ch/epfl/bbp/uima/laucher/Pipeline.java) on top of UIMA.

Comment: I am also using uimaFit, but as war as I tested, this doesn't enforce the presence either, am I wrong?